# How to write a loop in python to find HTML tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, loops

The attached [text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gVwRH-TlRks-ZJtb6P8vd3WkqcrIIAa0/view?usp=sharing) contains data from 3 news articles scraped from a news website.  I would like to write a loop that will separate the metadata from the article body for each of these three articles. The code below works for a single news article only (i.e., if I keep only one article in the text file). People have previously suggested using beautiful soup and regular expressions, but please note that I just want to modify the existing code to add a loop, and not use any other methods/functions.

Note about the textfile:

1. H1 class tag denotes the start of each article. The tag div class=<div class="story-element story-element-text\”> denotes the body text of the article. The text is in a Non-English script, but the tags are all in English.

> ```
> with open('threenewsarticles.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as my_file:
>     rawData = my_file.read()
>     print(rawData)
>
>
> #Separating body text from metadata. This code only works if the textfile has one article.
>
> articleStart = rawData.find("<div class=\"story-element story-element-text\">")
> articlemetaData = rawData[:articleStart]
> articleBody = rawData[articleStart:]
> print(articlemetaData)
> print("*******")
> print(articleBody)
> print("*******")
> ```

```
> The output should be like this for 3 articles
> 
> <h1 class=………</div>
> 
> *******
> 
> <div class= ……</div>
> 
> *******
> 
> <h1 class=………</div>
> 
> *******
> 
> <div class= ……</div>
> 
> *******
> 
> <h1 class=………</div>
> 
> *******
> 
> <div class= ……</div>
```

Comment: with `beautifulsoup` it would be more easy

Comment: the text file has python `lists`

Comment: I'm guessing that's why the find method isn't working? Is there an alternative way to search for tags in this case?